# how to sort list of names satisfying below

Tags: string

The answer to be in any programing language satisfying following conditions

- Only the first letter of each part of the name should be capital.
- All the parts of the name except the last part should be represented by only two characters.
- The first character should be the first letter of the part and should be capitalized.
- The second character should be `.` .

example:
Input:

```
mahatma gandhi
Mohndas KaramChand gandhi
```

Output:

```
M. Gandhi
M. K. Gandhi
```

Comment: I don't know, what would satisfy you? I suggest a bogo sort based on the number of vowels in the name, it would be very satisfying to me if the list was sorted this way.

Comment: Which language is this? Please add an appropriate tag.

Comment: add more detail on this, and what you have done on this so far by adding some code snippet.
Add programming language in your tags you are talking about

Comment: SO is a great place for getting specific help with code you've actually tried implementing. If you have tried to solve this problem, please  show us what you have so far. An example of the expected output would also be helpful, since it's hard from your question to figure out exactly what you want the code to do.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], show us what you've done, what you expect and what is failing.  At that point we may be able to help you.  What we won't do is write your code for you :(

Answer (score 1):

Please try if the following Java code can help you.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "mahatma gandhi\n" +
                "Mohndas KaramChand gandhi\nVijay singh";
        char[] chars = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(chars[i])) {
                chars[i + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);
        String output = String.valueOf(chars);
        String[] parts1 = output.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts1.length; i++) {
            String[] names = parts1[i].split(" ");
            String[] initials = output.split(" ");
            String lastname = names[names.length - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < names.length - 1; j++) {
                initials[j] = names[j].substring(0, 1);
                System.out.print(initials[j] + ".");    
            }
            System.out.println(" " + lastname);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
M. Gandhi
M.K. Gandhi
V. Singh
```

You can try different versions of the input string, or change the program to read the string from a file or from the console. I hope it works for you.